# What's the meaning of "guest spot" in "We have a guest spot on the Tonight Show"?

Tags: meaning

I think that "solo spot" has the same meaning, but I don't know the meaning either.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 2):

If you check with [CED](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spot?showCookiePolicy=true) you would realize

> **spot**
>
> a position or length of time in a show assigned to a specific performer

Answer (score 2):

In the parlance of television production, a "spot" is simply an appearance role. An actor may say something like "I got a spot in a commercial". They have a role appearing in a commercial.

Aa guest spot is an appearance role for a guest. A guest is someone who is not part of the regular cast.

I have never heard "guest spot" refer to a guest crew member (someone who does not have an appearing role). However, the Tonight Show is a little different from most television productions. Some crew members will frequently have appearance roles while they are doing their regular job (like announcing or operating a camera).

A solo spot follows from this. It simply means appearing alone on screen.

Answer (score 1):

A person who is set to appear on a talk show makes a "guest spot". See this [example](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/ustv/news/a450579/matt-damon-makes-first-official-guest-spot-on-jimmy-kimmel-live.html):

> Matt Damon makes first official **guest spot** on 'Jimmy Kimmel Live'.

Comment: Is there any difference between “to do a guest spot" and "to make a guest spot"?

Comment: "Do a guest spot" sounds much less idiomatic, almost ungrammatical, and I would use "make a guest spot" in every case like this, but I can't see any difference in meaning. However, an expression that you are more likely to hear than either one of these is "makes a guest appearance".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your TV show has a fixed or "regular" cast or crew, anyone who is not part of this regular cast or crew is new, or a *guest*.

Guest spot implies that the regular crew members occupy the usual ***spots*** , and a guest appearing on the show therefore occupies a ***guest spot*** .